# Configuring codeigniter with .env doesn't work for me

Tags: php, configuration, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to configure solr endpoint in codeigniter by using .env. I do the following:

1. I created a configuration class SolrConfigEndpoints

```
namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class SolrConfigEndpoints extends BaseConfig
{
    public $ptv = array(
        'endpoint' => array(
            'localhost' => array(
                'scheme' => 'http', # or https
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 8983,
                'path' => '/',
                'core' => 'course_catalog',
            )
        )
    );
}
```

2. I configured the values in .env as in the follow:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# SOLR
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

Config\SolrConfigEndpoints.ptv.endpoint.localhost.host='localhost'
Config\SolrConfigEndpoints.ptv.endpoint.localhost.port=8983
Config\SolrConfigEndpoints.ptv.endpoint.localhost.path='/'
Config\SolrConfigEndpoints.ptv.endpoint.localhost.core='ptv'
```

3. In my model I try to access .env data

```
$config = getenv();        
d($config); // something like a var_dump
```

and the SolrConfigEndpoints variables don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the Configurations from the SolrConfigEndpoints, so you will have to first create an instance like this : `$config = config('SolrConfigEndpoints');` Then you can access the property of `$config` object like a normal object. Idea here is to make the configurations easily available anywhere in the Project.

Whereas, .env properties that have been declared are just to replace the original properties that are defined in your configurations. To access any env variable. You have to use `getenv('key_name')`.

Reference : https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/configuration.html?highlight=baseconfig